# Newsletter Subscriber - Grid not loading

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.9, under news letter ---- newsletter subscriber --- grid is missing, its blank
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit your index.php file of root folder uncomment below line from this file.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

It will show you error so you can solve it.

Comment: I did but still not getting error, stuck from few days :(

Comment: Its Not  a Magento or coding Bug Please check server configuration May be you are missing something in server infra.

Comment: any suggestion on server configuration